# Why is last-child not working?

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to give my table td's a border-bottom apart from the last td. Where am I going wrong?

CSS

```
.rack  {
    border-left: 15px solid #959595;
}

.rack td {
    border-bottom: 15px solid #f05f28;
    width:100%;
}

.rack td:last-child {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="rack" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5ezyb2e9/2/)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you are misunderstanding how the `:last-child` selector works.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child):

> The `:last-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the last child element of its parent.

What you are doing with `.rack td:last-child` is selecting the `<td>` that is the last child of it's parent `<tr>`, meaning all of them.

Simply select the `<tr>` that is the `:last-child`(or `:last-of-type`), then select it's child `<td>`:

```
.rack tr:last-child td {
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a3tx5gc9/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand it clearly now.

Answer (score 3):

You should replace `.rack td:last-child` with `.rack tr:last-child td`. `:last-child` is applied to the last child relative to its respective parent element, so you want to select the `td` of the *last `tr`*.

Comment: Damn I must have tried so many variations apart from that. Thanks man!